# MySQL - Difficulty getting sum with other data between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, invision-power-board

I am using the Invision Power Board suite for purchases, but they do not provide a way to get the total a customer has paid. So I am attempting to write an SQL Query for this information. My knowledge of SQL is extremely limited, so ... I may be taking the wrong approach.

From what I have gathered, the information I need is on two tables, but the way it outputs is not useful to me since it outputs every individual purchase, with only the member's unique ID (relatively useless in bulk operations and examination)

I have so far gotten to this point...

```
SELECT member_id, email, name, 
SUM(ibf_nexus_invoices.i_total) as SUM_TOTAL
FROM ibf_members
RIGHT JOIN ibf_nexus_invoices ON ibf_members.member_id = ibf_nexus_invoices.i_member
WHERE ibf_nexus_invoices.I_status = "paid";
```

This takes everything from the members table and the invoices table, and outputs it like this..

```
------------------------------------------------------------
member_id      |    email         | name      | SUM_TOTAL  |
------------------------------------------------------------
    4          | email@domain.com | "Derek"   | 184.22     |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

At first glance, this looks like what I want. But it only returns one person, not all of the people in the member's list. Is anyone versed enough with SQL to help steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
GROUP BY member_id
```

to the end of the query to get a row per person. Otherwise, aggregate functions like `SUM()` combine all the rows in the result.